# excel formula convert minutes to hundredths

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm new to excel and my leader has asked me to prepare an excel formula that do the following time equation :

04:15 should converted as 04:25

18:30 should converted as 18:50

33:45 should converted as 33:75

30:14 should converted as 30:23

This formula should convert minutes to hundredths and **should not** do any thing with the hours such as above example.

I have searched for hours and could find the exact excel formula such this one.

Please guys help my.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you *sure* you want the output formatted with a colon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got this:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[hh]") & ":" & FLOOR(MINUTE(A1)*100/60,1)
```

Note the use of the `TEXT` function. This is to format the times such as `30:45`, to ensure the output is `30` and not `6`.

Comment: Dear rhughes, thaaaaaaaaaaanks that what i looking for.

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark this as the answer to help others out.

Comment: Yes i will but i should have 15 reputation to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Multiply your times by 24.

For example, if cell A1 has 4:15 then =A1*24 will give 4.25.

Make sure that the cell containing the above formula is formatted as a decimal. (Excel might automatically convert it to a time-type format so you'll have to convert it back).

Comment: Yes that's rather cute, plus one.

Answer (score 2):

`=TEXT(A1,"[hh]") & ":" & FLOOR(MINUTE(A1)*100/60,1)` is **NOT** correct entirely:

If you convert 1:15, this converts it to 1:25 (correct)

If you convert 1:01, this converts to 1:1 (not correct)

This is the correct answer:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[hh]") & ":" & TEXT( FLOOR(MINUTE(A1)*100/60,1), "00")
```

or for a decimal point:

```
=TEXT(A1,"[hh]") & "." & TEXT( FLOOR(MINUTE(A1)*100/60,1), "00")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another one

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1*24,"00.00"),".",":")
```